# Split string with value and order criteria

Tags: sql-server, csv, t-sql, sql-order-by

Hei I'd love some help with splitting strings in Table1:

```
  ID           Level    Options          OptionCodes
  A5CF-601     G;8      1,2,3            4958,2669,26
  88C0-0EA     G;9      1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8  2669,21,670,267,13,738,85,55
  BE95-196     G;6      Q,L,S,T          6705,6694,6693,6691
```

After splitting both 'Options' and 'OptionCodes' I need to concatenate 'level' with each value from 'Options' with a '-'. 
Then relate each concatenation to 'OptionCodes' in the same order as they appear in the string.

The desired result would be:

```
 LevelOption   OptionCode
 G;8 - 1       4958     
 G;8 - 2       2669     
 G;8 - 3       26       
 G;9 - 1       2669     
 G;9 - 2       21       
 G;9 - 3       760      
 G;9 - 4       267      
 G;9 - 5       13       
 G;9 - 6       738      
 G;9 - 7       85       
 G;9 - 8       55       
 G;6 - Q       6705     
 G;6 - L       6694     
 G;6 - S       6693     
 G;6 - T       6691
```

I have done some tryouts with string_split, substring, charindex, etc. But still can't get my head around it. There is one restriction to my use of SQL server: I have no rights to create functions, which makes it a bit more challenging. Anyways,thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Is options always simple ascending sequence starting with 1 as in the example? Are there always the same number of values within options and OptionCodes?

Comment: This is possibly the most backwards implementation of a SQL schema I've ever seen. Can you change the structure?

Comment: @BarneyL I see now sometimes I have letters in Options, but the relationship is always ascending. Yes. And yes, there are always the same number of values within Options and OptionCodes

Comment: SQL Server version? And is it guaranteed that options and OptionCodes will not contain repeated values e.g. `a,b,c,a`?

Comment: @JacobH I wish I could, this is not my database design I just work with ETL now...

Comment: @SalmanA Yes it is guaranteed, all Options are unique in each row.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio      15.0.18142.0

Comment: The biggest issue with STRING_SPLIT is that it does not return the ordinal position of each element. In your case you absolutely need this critical piece of information. You could probably kludge this into existence using some temp tables with identity columns. But the handicap of not being allowed to create a split function is killing you here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`STRING_SPLIT` does not return the index position of substrings. A clumsy solution is to use `CHARINDEX` to locate the position of substring inside the main string and use the result to number the substrings. Unfortunately this requires that the string does not contain repeated substrings.

The query would look like:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT ID
         , Level
         , o.value AS ov
         , c.value AS ocv
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + o.value + ',', ',' + Options + ',')) AS rn1
         , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CHARINDEX(',' + c.value + ',', ',' + OptionCodes + ',')) AS rn2
    FROM t
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Options, ',') AS o
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(OptionCodes, ',') AS c
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn1 = rn2
```

[Demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=659b6bc31814a9ada59f1e16dadf5fc8)

Comment: Interesting way to tackle the huge miss of MS not including ordinal position. If they had done string_split correctly it would have been such a super awesome addition. Unfortunately they missed the boat big time with such a simple piece of information.

Comment: Works perfect. Thanks!